# How to connect YEARS and SERVING

Tags: nouns

I want to modify the verb phrase (seemed unscathed)
by adding adverbial phrases like this.
Which one (from a - d) is grammatically correct ?

```
He seemed unscathed
  a) by his long years    serving a prison sentence.
  b) by his long years'   serving a prison sentence.
  c) by his long years of serving a prison sentence.
  d) by his long years,   serving a prison sentence.
```

Comment: Idiomatic would be: **by his long years in prison.** But if you have to choose, go for a).

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Or **by his long prison sentence**.